# how to add a double type in kotlin hashmap?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have code :

```
val value: HashMap<String, Any> = hashMapOf()
value["sender_id"] = userId!!
value["name"] = firstname!!
value["text"] = et_search_box.text.toString()
value["avatar"] = avatar!!
value["date"] = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.toDouble()
```

how to add date types to double?

[example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXAuG.png)

Comment: What is `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: timestamp in firebase

Comment: i meant the type of TIMESTAMP and if its a class put it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the image from the link you have shared, `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` is of type `String`.

Depending on the date-format, you need to parse the String to some Time object.
Then that can be converted to double.
For e.g., I have used `java.time.Instant` to convert ISO 8601 date string to double.

```
val instant = Instant.parse("2020-05-13T05:05:52.945571Z")
val d: Double = instant.epochSecond + instant.nano / 1_000_000_000.0
```

Note for Android: `java.time.Instant` is available since Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) is has two specific functions [getSeconds()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp#getSeconds()) and [getNanoseconds()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp#getNanoseconds()) to resolve the time in any other units.

For example to get the time in seconds with upto 9 digits of accuracy (nano second accuracy)

```kotlin
val timestampInSeconds: Double = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.run {
    getSeconds().toDouble + getNanoseconds.toDouble() / 1_000_000_000
}
```

This is very accurate, however timestamps are usually represented by milliseconds and can easily be deserialized to a Date object if you want to, for instance [java.util.Date](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/Date) uses millisecond value to evaluate the date object.

To get standard millisecond value:

```kotlin
val stdTimestampMillis: Long = ServerValue.TIMESTAMP.toDate().getTime()

// to deserialize it to Timestamp/Date object later
val date: Date = Date(stdTimestampMillis)
val timestamp: Timestamp = Timestamp(date)
```